# How can I use aws-iot-device-sdk NPM module with Angular 11 ? (it throws fs, path, & tls errors on build)

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, iot

I maintain an browser-based Angular app that was at version 5.6. This app has two components that subscribe to an IOT topic and listen for updates (no pub, just sub).

**We need to upgrade to Agnular 11.0.3. I have completed that work. But now the aws-iot-device-sdk NPM module caucuses these errors when I try to run the local web server or run a build:**

```
Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[PATH_TO]/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/common/lib'
Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[PATH_TO]/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/device'
Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[PATH_TO]/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/device'
Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '[PATH_TO]/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/device/lib'
```

**I have spent many hours pulling my hair out on this issue. Our front-end (browser) IOT code has been working perfectly for the last few years. But the upgrade to Angular 11.0.3 has to happen and this issue is a big blocker.**

---

**SAMPLE CODE FROM OUR APPLICATION:**

*(Our package.json is at the end)*

**The xxxx-app.component.ts file:**

```
import { AwsIotService } from '../../shared/awsIot/awsIot.service';

this.awsIotService.getNewIotConnection(this.iotTopic, this.iotUrl, (iotClient) => {
    //cache the iotClient
    this.iotClient = iotClient;

    //handle the iotClient's message event
    iotClient.on('message', (topic, message) => {
        // process the message here:
        console.log('IOT Message received:');
        console.dir(message);
    });
});
```

**awsIotService.ts:**

In the code below, "iotUrl" points to a custom service we wrote that provides the details needed by the browser-based Angular app in order to connect and subscribe:

```
awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk'); //simply requiring that NPM module causes the errors stated above

getNewIotConnection (topic, iotUrl, callback) {
    this.httpClient.get(iotUrl).subscribe(responseData => {

         const client = this.awsIot.device({
                port: 443,
                protocol: 'wss',
                region: responseData.region,
                host: responseData.iotEndpoint,
                secretKey: responseData.secretKey,
                accessKeyId: responseData.accessKey,
                sessionToken: responseData.sessionToken,
            });

            // subscribe to the topic
            client.on('connect', () => client.subscribe(topic));

            // call the callback
            callback(client);
     });
}
```

---

**UP-TO-DATE SUGGESTIONS THAT I HAVE TRIED:**

**1** - I have tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-iot-device-sdk-v2

....but have not found the documentation helpful... I hope I am missing something here.

**2** I have tried AWS amplify and followed this tutorial:

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/angular

...but using AWS amplify to solve this issue would require a re-work of the back-end we built and seems like getting a new transmission for a flat tire (i.e. just need to subscribe to an IOT topic).

---

**OLDER WORKAROUNDS THAT I HAVE TRIED:**

**3** I tried adding this to package.json:

```
"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

...that did not work.

**4** I tried adding this to package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...other packages
  "mqtt": "2.15.1",
  "minimist": "1.2.0",
  "websocket-stream": "^5.0.1",
  "crypto-js": "3.1.6"
}
```

...that did not work.

**5** I tried the patch.js approach detailed here:

https://gist.github.com/niespodd/1fa82da6f8c901d1c33d2fcbb762947d

...that did not work.

**6** I tried adding this to webpack.config.js :

```
resolve: {
  fallback: {
    fs: false
  }
}
```

...that did not work.

**7** I tried adding this to webpack.config.js :

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

...that did not work (only works in older WebPack.)

---

**Our package.json** (just dependencies & devDependencies):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.3",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "^1.2.0",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^2.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.0.0",
    "@turf/inside": "^5.0.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "@types/unist": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
    "aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "exports-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^5.0.0",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.1.13",
    "postcss-import": "^13.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "retyped-stripe-tsd-ambient": "^0.0.0-0",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.11",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
```

Comment: It sounds like you’re trying to require a NodeJS package..? That won’t work in a browser..

Comment: @MikeOne - The code in the question has worked perfectly for years (literally). It appears that one of the dependencies of the aws-iot-device-sdk module depends on the "fs" module, and Angular no longer allows that module. What I can't understand is how there is no strait forward way to work around this. Using AWS Amplify really seems like overkill.

Comment: Fs is FileSystem. Only available in node, not in a browser. You might have the wrong package

Comment: @MikeOne - not sure if you are getting my point: Yes, I understand what the fs module is. What I am saying is that implementing the aws-iot-device-sdk module was working fine and did so for years. The newest version of Angular does not allow that dependency. There are numerous workarounds out there (detailed in my question), but they are all now out-dated. I'm hoping to find one that works.

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, he has the CORRECT package. You misunderstood the OP and you're confusing the beginners of which AWS IoT package they might use...

Comment: @KenTaylor did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://dev.to/eelayoubi/decoupling-an-app-using-aws-iot-577a) help? The author seemed to have/avoid the same trouble as you.  He mentions:

```
   "browser": {
       "fs": false,
       "tls": false,
       "path": false
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following environment:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.13
Node: 16.13.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: linux x64

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.13
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.13
@angular/cdk                    12.2.12
@schematics/angular             12.2.13
ng-packagr                      12.2.5
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

And in order to complement the approach of @kackle123, the following worked for me in `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "net": false,
    "path": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false,
    "fs": false
}
```

But it only mute the error outputs, and the package will not work anyways.